# Create input name using array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input

I want to create all required input fields based on a given array, getting the name of the field from the array. What i have done and been using for some years now is the code below, i was wondering if there could be an "easier" to handle and expand way..

```
foreach($value as $obj => $entry):
    if (is_array($entry) ):
        foreach($entry as $entKey => $ent):
            if (is_array($ent) ):
                foreach($ent as $enty => $subEnt):

                    if(is_array($subEnt)):

                        foreach($subEnt as $pg => $pgbldr):

                            if(is_array($pgbldr)):
                                foreach($pgbldr as $za => $zxc):
                                    $block .= '<input type="hidden" name="pageBuilder['.$key.']['.$obj.']['.$entKey.']['.$enty.']['.$pg.']['.$za.']" value="'.htmlentities($zxc).'">';
                                endforeach;
                            else:
                                $block .= '<input type="hidden" name="pageBuilder['.$key.']['.$obj.']['.$entKey.']['.$enty.']['.$pg.']" value="'.htmlentities($pgbldr).'">';
                            endif;

                        endforeach;
                    else:
                        $block .= '<input type="hidden" name="pageBuilder['.$key.']['.$obj.']['.$entKey.']['.$enty.']" value="'.htmlentities($subEnt).'">';
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            else:
                $block .= '<input type="hidden" name="pageBuilder['.$key.']['.$obj.']['.$entKey.']" value="'.htmlentities($ent).'">';
            endif;
        endforeach;
    else:
        $block .= '<input type="hidden" name="pageBuilder['.$key.']['.$obj.']" value="'.htmlentities($entry).'">';
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Array Example:

```
Array
(
    [MegaSlider_31922] => Array
        (
            [type] => MegaSlider
            [randId] => MegaSlider_31922
            [visible] => 1
            [height] => 768
            [speed] => 5000
            [tabs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [horizontal_alignment] => left
                            [vertical_alignment] => top
                            [text_1] => 
                            [text_1_color] => #000000
                            [text_1_size] => 
                            ...
                        )

                )

            [Settings] => Array
                (
                    [background_color] => #000000
                    ... 
                )

        )

    [ServiceBox_42933] => Array
        (
            [type] => ServiceBox
            [randId] => ServiceBox_42933
            [visible] => 1
            [text_color] => #2a53ea
            [tab] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => ΔΩΡΕΑΝ ΜΕΤΑΦΟΡΙΚΑ
                            [subtitle] => ΓΙΑ ΠΑΡΑΓΓΕΛΙΕΣ ΑΝΩ ΤΩΝ 40€
                            ...
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 4 ΤΡΟΠΟΙ ΠΛΗΡΩΜΗΣ
                            ...
                        )

                )

            [Settings] => Array
                (
                    [layoutwidth] => fullwidth
                    [background_color] => #000000
                    ...
                )

        )

    [CallOutActionBannersv1_74441] => Array
        (
            [type] => CallOutActionBannersv1
            [randId] => CallOutActionBannersv1_74441
            [visible] => 1
            [tab] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 
                            [title_color] => #000000
                            ...
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [title] => 
                            [title_color] => #000000
                            ...
                        )

                )

            [Settings] => Array
                (
                    [background_color] => #000000
                    [Image] => 
                    ...

        )

)
```

Comment: I think you can separate the function by `type` in each array. For example, if `type`=`ServiceBox`, you call a function to create ServiceBox. Each `type` uses different functions to create different items. It would be easier to maintain.

Comment: I dont want each type to depend on a function because developers could create their own structure. The current array is stored in JSON format, so there is no standard structure. I just want to built the form inputs based on "every" json.
The only check is if the current array has also children and os on

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here (https://gist.github.com/anjan011/a9789eb7ecb59e1c0f02). Super easy, on first try it works with a few modifications which needed for me and security issues if any, but could save you great deal of time.